# Is there a python function for authentication user delete?

Tags: javascript, python, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to migrate my JavaScript Firebase function over to Python, which looks like this:

```js
exports.deleteUserDoc = functions.auth.user().onDelete(user => {
    // function body
});
```

However, after lots of looking around through the Python docs, I couldn't find an equivalent event listener. Am I missing something, or is it not supported yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no Python direct equivalent when it comes to the `onDelete()` event listener you mentioned.

Upon searching for references I have check it under the firebase/functions-samples here is the link to check it: [github](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/77166a3d241fd20cb0890d980df87f8135f6719a/Node-1st-gen/quickstarts/email-users/functions/index.js)

You can also check the [Python samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/77166a3d241fd20cb0890d980df87f8135f6719a/Python/quickstarts)

There is a possible workaround:

You can use the [firebase_admin.auth module](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth)

Use the specific method [get_user_by_email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#get_user_by_email) to search the UID of the user you wanted to delete it and then call the method [delete_user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#delete_user) to delete it.

You can also check this out [Delete a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think you misread my question, I'm looking for the Python equivalent

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I have improved my answer. Thank you